# Build fails for cloud function in Google Cloud Platform after disabling Cloud Build API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I unintentionally enabled cloud build API, which created images in cloud storage. Having deleted these and disabled Cloud Build API and Container Registry API, the cloud functions no longer run and show the error:

'Build Failed: Cloud Build API has not been used in project XXXX before or it is disabled...'

telling me to enable the API. But I am not trying to build a container so do not want to enable the API. Is there something else I need to disable other than the APIs mentioned?

My cloud functions have a cloud storage trigger but also don't work with an HTTP trigger. When I try to edit the code in the cloud function using Python 3.7 runtime I get the error:

'Cloud Build API is required to use the runtime selected'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a function targeting the python 3.7 runtime, you are actually *implicitly* going to build a container using Cloud Build.  That's how Cloud Functions operates internally.  The details of that container are just abstracted away behind the tools you use the deploy the function.  Since Cloud Build is used to implement process, so you will need to have that API enabled in order to deploy.